# "Re" resolve resources with angular ui router without reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the following code to resolve a resource when the main state is loaded. Is it possible to re - resolve the resource without reloading the page? I am avoiding reload so that the user experience is not affected.

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'publicApp/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl as mainCtrl',
            resolve: {
                userData: ["UserApi", function (UserApi) {
                    return UserApi.getUserData().$promise;
                }]
            }
        })


    .controller('MainCtrl', function (userData) {
        console.log(userData.something);
    })
```

Since is a public site, the user can visit any page without logging in but when the user logs in the page must customize based on the user data.

**EDIT**

I am using a modal for login so the state doesn't reload after logging in, I was thinking of throwing an event on `$rootScope` and then add listeners in controllers to load them again. But this doesn't look good, so I am looking for a better way

I currently have two options:

1. Reload page - will effect the user experience, so its the last option
2. Throw an event for the login modal and catch it in other controllers

Any better ideas?

Comment: If the user is not logged in, the userData promise should not be resolved. Probably better calling the getUserData() from controllers that can be used in both logged out and in. Then when the user logs in, resolve this promise and the controller can update it's data.

Answer (score 3):

Try using state reload once promise is resolved

`$state.reload();`

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a NO reload option.

Comment: He said without reloading the page. $state.reload() does not reload the page. It reloads the state.